# How to add javascript code, in html <head> tag using Slim, with id?

Tags: javascript, html, slim-lang

In the following snippet of Slim code, how do we add id/type attributes to the javascript tag (similar to script tag in html) in the head tag.

The [Slim docs](http://slim-lang.com/) does not show how to do this beyond simple alert statement.

P.S. Code kept short for brevity

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title
      | Example
    <!-- How to add script id and type in the following code? -->
    javascript:
      alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!')
  body
    #root
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs link](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Inline_html__) you posted, you can simply inline the script tag:

```
doctype html
html
  head
   title
     | Example
   <script id="ID_HERE">alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!')</script>
  body
    #root
```

Comment: From what I have tested, we need a pipe to render the js code à la, `<script id="ID_HERE"> | alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!')</script>`

Answer (score 1):

After some research and picking info from here and there, I found an alternative to the above answer.

```
doctype html
html
  head
   title
     | Example
   script#ID_HERE type="text/javascript"
     | JS CODE
  body
    #root
```